# Mac OS X 10.6.7 Java Path Current JDK confusing

Tags: java, macos

I have trouble understanding (actual paths vs links) for multiple java versions on my Mac OSX. Normally in windows if I have multiple versions installed in my machine, I can just take the path of which ever version I want and use it. But in MAC OS X I undertand that there is something called links that is being pointed to CurrentJDK, and if I want to use a different version I will need to change the link to CurrentJdk right? But what is confusing for me is that as you can see below all my versions are pointing to the same CurrentJDK which means all versions point to current version? I was expecting only one of them would be pointing to CurrentJDK and I could just change it to which ever one I need which is not the case here. All I need to know is how to find the bin(Commands) folder path for each version, so that I can just use it to point to CurrentJDK? Also tell me how to change the link to CurrentJDK.

```
$ java -version

java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

$ pwd

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions


$ ls -l

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    5 Mar 20 11:12 1.3 -> 1.3.1
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 Dec  2  2009 1.3.1
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 Mar 20 11:12 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel  340 Mar 20 11:13 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Mar 20 11:12 Current -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 Mar 20 11:12 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
```

Comment: run `which java` to recognising which version you are currently used. then run `/usr/libexec/java_home -version <what version you like such as 1.8>`. It will print out related java home folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most possibly you only have one jdk installed, thus all the soft links points to the same jdk. If you however did have multiple jdks installed you would need to choose which one to use with the 'Java Preferences' app in your /Application/Utilities.

Soft links are by the way created with the `ln -s` command from Terminal.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I looked at Java Preferences and it looks like I have just one version Java SE 6. So if I had multiple versions, if I just enable one of them, my CurrentJDK gets pointed to the selected version? I actually needed to use both java 5 and 1.6. Since I already have 6, is it still possible to install version 5 also without screwing the existing 6 version?

Comment: Yes you can have both 1.5 and 1.6. And for programs launched from the command line you can still set JAVA_HOME to point to the desired jdk. The jdk set by 'Java Preferences' is the jdk used by the system, and when programs is opened by clicking icons.

Comment: Right now I see my JAVA_HOME is empty. Does it mean setting JAVA_HOME is not mandatory and just enabling in java preferences utility is enough to point required version to CurrentJDK?

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME is not mandatory, but if you  install jdk-1.5 you still want to have jdk-1.6 being used by the system, so then setting JAVA_HOME would enable you to use any jdk, while the system uses the official jdk-1.6

Comment: One final question, so if I set the JAVA_HOME to required version, does it take care of CurrentJDK link as well? Or should I set the link along with JAVA_HOME?

Comment: No, the 'Java Preferences' program takes care of the CurrentJDK link

Comment: Quick update: The Java settings/preference application is now located in System Preferences -> Other - Java and not in  /Application/Utilities

Comment: Not anymore. There's nothing in System Preferences in Mojave. Under Mojave, I found the JDK here: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk

Answer (score 67):

For different types of JDKs or installations, you will have different paths.

On Mac OS X Mavericks, the path I found as following:

1) Built-in JRE default:

```
 /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

2) JDKs downloaded from Apple:

```
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

3) JDKs downloaded from Oracle:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 5):

Just run following commands:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install jenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
  oracle64-1.8.0.45 added
  1.8.0.45 added
  1.8 added

$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
  oracle64-1.7.0.79 added
  1.7.0.79 added
  1.7 added

$ jenv versions
* system (set by /Users/wanluwang/.jenv/version)
  1.7
  1.7.0.79
  1.8
  1.8.0.45
  oracle64-1.7.0.79
  oracle64-1.8.0.45

$ java -version
  java version "1.8.0_45"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

$ jenv global oracle64-1.7.0.79

$ java -version
  java version "1.7.0_79"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Rajas-MacBook-Pro:/$ $ brew update
-bash: $: command not found
Rajas-MacBook-Pro:/$ $ brew install jenv
-bash: $: command not found
Rajas-MacBook-Pro:/$ $ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
-bash: $: command not found
Rajas-MacBook-Pro:/$ $ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
-bash: $: command not found
Rajas-MacBook-Pro:/$ $jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
-bash: add: command not found

Comment: @raja777m ~ No need to include the leading '$' in your command execution on the terminal. Leave that out and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Technical Q&A Java Questions:

User Preferences

On Mac OS X, the Java runtime provides the java.util.prefs API which is backed by the standard Mac OS X Preferences API and directories. Simply using this pure Java API reads and stores your application's preferences in ~/Library/Preferences in a Mac OS X property list file. For applications that may already have their own preferences format, these preferences should be stored in the ~/Library/Preferences directory as well. This directory can be reached from Java code by creating a file with the path of System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Preferences/" + "com.example.your.Application". An application that should have global preferences across all users could instead reside in /Library/Preferences, however this directory is not writable by non-admin users.

Answer (score 0):

set $JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
in your .bash_profile

or export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home);

echo $JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Ventura,
JDK downloaded from Oracle

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```