# Default JRE path not set on eclipse plugin project in MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I create a Eclipse plugin project in MAC OSX. After build this Product,  I tried set JRE using **Search...** button but it's not working.

My JDK is installed properly in MAC OSX.

SO can someone tell me Why this happen.

[image]

Comment: Try add your JRE path on [this][1]                   .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing

Answer (score 0):

Pass "**org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx**" plugin in your eclipse while create Product build.

It's Working for me.

Thanks.