# JDK path in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, jdk6

I have downloaded JDK 6 from the following link:https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572. I installed the jdk succesfully. I would like to know the path that this jdk was installed. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can't you just do a search?

Comment: There is a specific folder that the jdks in OSX Yosemite are installed, i would like to know where this folder is. I haven't made a search yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
[Mac OS X 10.6.7 Java Path Current JDK confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing)

JDK downloaded from Apple:

```
 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

From Oracle:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try these locations.