# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I wanted to use the ./gradlew build command but I always get this response:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I'm very new to this and don't know a lot about the different Library Folders, but the path "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk" should be right. I can use the **cd** command to go into the folder, which means it exists, right?

My standard Java JDK is a different one and when I use the Library that I can also find via "Go To" at the top of the screen and I go to the Java folder, the JDK 1.8 is not there. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I used `echo export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk" >> ~/.zshrc` to set the JAVA_HOME variable and I used the **env** command to see if it got set (which it did).

I really need help because I need it for my first Software Engineering Project at university.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos)

Comment: It should be `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home` i believe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac OS X 10.6.7 Java Path Current JDK confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing)

Answer (score 1):

The `java_home` binary will configure this for you.  It will spit out the correct path for JAVA_HOME based on the version you provide, else the latest.

```
# get version 11
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v11`
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home

# get version 18
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v18`
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.jdk/Contents/Home

# get the latest version
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
lane.maxwell@tesla:~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/lane.maxwell/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-19.0.1/Contents/Home
```